creating and activating network interface from command line
in RHEL-8.10 or later if it matters,
I only know how to configure a functional network interface from the GUI interface... from Applications - System Tools - Settings - Network
When Network Manager is not being used where NetworkManager.service is disabled and the Settings - Network graphical interface becomes unavailable, and also when in the runlevel 3 multi-user.target state, how from the command line do you identify and then configure and activate a network?  And also create it if it does not show up via ip a or ifconfig.

If you want to create a persistent interface configuration, you must be using NetworkManager or an alternative like systemd-networkd. Anything you create using commands like ip won't persist across a reboot. You can use the nmcli command to create NetworkManager-managed interfaces from the command line; the process is already well documented.

A network interface is normally created as an OS-recognized object when its driver starts up and probes the interface hardware.
A classic ifconfig with no options would only show configured network interfaces, but ifconfig -a would show all network interfaces that have a working driver loaded (either as a module, or built-in to the kernel).
Likewise, ip a[ddress] will show configured IP addresses; showing the active interfaces they're attached to is just a side effect. If you want to see all interfaces that have drivers loaded, including unconfigured ones, similar to ifconfig -a, you would have to use ip link instead.
When the graphical interface is not available, there's still a number of ways to control NetworkManager: nmtui is a friendly, dialog-based tool that works on text-only terminals, and nmcli is the ultimate command-line access to NetworkManager: it allows the manipulation of all NetworkManager parameters for a network interface.
By default, NetworkManager seems to auto-create an initial connection definition for wired network interfaces detected at installation/first boot time, and seems to name them something like "Wired connection 1".
If configuring a network interface with nmcli, I would first ensure the interface definition is tied to a particular interface, and assign it a more descriptive name:
nmcli c show                       # list existing connection definitions
nmcli c show "Wired connection 1"  # list a specific connection
nmcli c mod "Wired connection 1" connection.id Production   # rename connection
nmcli c mod Production connection.interface-name eno1    # apply this connection to eno1 only

After that, I might set a static IP address, netmask, gateway and DNS server. In this environment, IPv6 is not yet available, and we explicitly disable it to prevent uncontrolled activation of IPv6 when its deployment finally begins.
nmcli c mod Production ipv4.method static
nmcli c mod Production ipv4.addresses 192.0.2.10/24
nmcli c mod Production ipv4.gateway 192.0.2.1
nmcli c mod Production ipv4.dns 192.0.2.53
nmcli c mod Production ipv6.method disable

And then, to make all these settings effective:
nmcli c up Production

To ensure the connection will be activated automatically at boot:
nmcli c mod Production connection.autoconnect yes

If the interface might not always be plugged in, you might want to tell the system to not hang up the boot waiting for it:
nmcli c mod Production ipv4.may-fail yes

